# Is this code thread-safe or is using a parameter to synchronize risky?

Tags: java, concurrency

```
private void doSomething(final Queue<Integer> stuff) {
        synchronized(stuff){
                Integer stuffId = stuff.poll();
        }
        etc
```

It worries me particularly that it is annotated with
@SuppressWarnings("SynchronizationOnLocalVariableOrMethodParameter")